# Can't get rid of an address in the GAL for online Outlook (no cache mode)

Tags: exchange

We have a multi-tenant exchange 2013 server.  A particular client has asked that remove disabled and deleted account from their GAL.  They only use on-line mode as their virtuals are in the same datacenter as the exchange server.

I've tried setting the attribute msExchHideFromAddressLists to TRUE but that doesn't seem to have worked for all of them.

I've mirrored settings from accounts where this has worked and then again, and out of the two stragglers: one fell off and the other is sticking.  They're both in the same exchange database.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you see the hidden email addresses via OWA?

How did you remove/disable mailboxes?(Do that in **ADUC** or **EAC**/**EMS**?)

Based on my test, if I disabled a mailbox via **ADUC** and modified the `msExchHideFromAddressLists` attribute in the ADUC, the legacy email address would still be in Outlook address book, but we could run the following command to hide it:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity <Mailbox Name> -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

However, if I disabled a mailbox via **EAC**/**EMS**, or removed it via **ADUC**, the legacy email address wouldn't show in Outlook address book any more. If you still see the legacy email addresses in the addressbook, I guess that the address lists hasn't been updated in Outlook, please try to run the following commands to update them, then restart Outlook and see if there is any difference:

```
Get-GlobalAddressList | Update-GlobalAddressList
Get-AddressList | Update-AddressList
```

Comment: I will give this a try tonight when some users fall off and I can grab a desktop to test.

Comment: It worked, I had done some in AD and the rest in EAC, this particular sticky wicket was done in AD.